# GitHub Workflow with Build Including Class Library in Another Repository

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

My .NET project builds successfully locally, but I cannot get a successful build with GitHub workflow.  The solution includes a main project in one repository and a class library solution in another repository.

```
D:
└── Source
    └── Repos
        ├── SweetSpot
        │   └── SweetSpot
        │       └── SweetSpot.csproj
        └── SweetBackend
            └── SweetBackend.csproj
```

I am getting errors that might indicate that built assemblies of the class library are expected to be included in the main project.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: The checkouts in your workflow would make it second repo nested to the first one. See [Checkout multiple repos (nested)](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-multiple-repos-nested). From your directory, it seems like you need to have them side by side to make this work. See [Checkout multiple repos (side by side)](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-multiple-repos-side-by-side) to configure this accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficultly is in understanding the directory structure GitHub uses when checking out the repositories.  When the first directory is checked out, the path is changed to a directory inside the repository, then the next repository is placed inside that subdirectory.

This can be resolved by explicitly specifying the path with checkout as below.

To get clarity on what is occurring, add a step that will recursively output the contents of the directories after checkout as below.

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-2019

    steps:
    - name: Checkout SweetSpot
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        path: ./SweetSpot

    - name: Checkout SweetBackend
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        repository: SweetTrading/SweetBackend
        ref: master
        token: ${{ secrets.ACCESSGITHUB_TOKEN }}
        path: ./SweetBackend

    - name: Go to root directory
      run: cd ./

    - name: Print directory structure
      working-directory: ./
      run: |
        echo "Directory structure:"
        ls -R
```